# Jquery change function on ionslider not working

Tags: jquery, slider, rangeslider

I have a ionslider in my project. I need to predict the slider change.
This is my slider

```
$("#myslider").ionRangeSlider();
```

on change function

```
$("#myslider").on('change',function(){
    var $this = $(this),
    from = $this.data("from"),
    to = $this.data("to");

   console.log(from + " - " + to);
});
```

But `'change'` function not working. Is this a correct way to predict the slider change? or is there anyway to do..  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `onChange` event of ionRangeSlider:

```
$("#range_43").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "single",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    from: 50,
    keyboard: true,
    onStart: function(data) {
        console.log("onStart");
    },
    onChange: function(data) {
        console.log("onChange");
    },
    onFinish: function(data) {
        console.log("onFinish");
    },
    onUpdate: function(data) {
        console.log("onUpdate");
    }
});
```

http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_interactions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$("#myslider").change(function(){
    console.log("check"); //check if it successfully enters .change function
    var $this = $(this),
    from = $this.data("from"),
    to = $this.data("to");

   console.log(from + " - " + to);
});
```

If it does not proceed with the 2nd console log, your variable values might have a problem. .change is supposed to by triggered in .ionRangeSlider()